# Menu Navigation and Partial Views Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a horizontal menu which is a Partial view inside one of Views, which is rendered inside the RenderBody section as shown here.
[image]

i have a div element below the partial view(menu).
Is it possible to load the div with different partial view when the user clicks on the navigation links above without using Ajax.Is it possible to use RenderAction to load the Partial View inside the div ?

Or is there any other way i can arrange the layout to make this possible ?

**UPDATE:**
I ended up putting the partial view menu on all the views.To my surprise, the menu section is not even flickering when i navigate from one view to another, after clicking the menu.So i think i am going to keep this approach unless someone advice other wise.

Thanks !

Comment: i cannot move the menu to the layout section, because layout section has other menus.

Comment: Ajax is really good at this, but if you can't go that route for some reason would Html.RenderPartial() work for you?

Comment: I did this with Ajax at first, but due to SEO reasons i removed the Ajax code. I thought google wont be able to crawl if used the Ajax approach. If i use RenderPartial, how can i trigger it when user clicks on different menus ? Thanks !

Comment: You could render all your partials on the initial page load, and have all of them hidden except the initial partial you want to load. Then when the user clicks a menu item, you can use jQuery to hide the current div shown, and show the div corresponding to the menu item clicked.